# In Python, Given a list of tuple, generate a list whose elements are sum of elements of contained tuples

Tags: python-2.7

Given a list of tuple, generate a list whose elements are sum of elements of contained tuples.
E.g. Input: [(1, 7), (1, 3), (3, 4, 5), (2, 2)]
Output: [8, 4, 12, 4]

Comment: This is off-topic for SO because it is just a problem statement, not a question. Please read the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple question and one with basic knowledge in python can do it.

```
a=input('Enter the list of tuples')
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(sum(a[i]))
```

I have not checked for simple answers. You can please check for them. And please do use python shell as you can easily find solutions of python codes in it.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please do accept it. :)